# Flink Streaming Job is Failed Automatically

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running a flink streaming job with parallelism 1 .

Suddenly after 8 hours job failed . It showed

```
Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@192.168.3.153:44863] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
2017-04-12 00:48:36,683 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnJobManager                          - Container container_e35_1491556562442_5086_01_000002 is completed with diagnostics: Container [pid=64750,containerID=container_e35_1491556562442_5086_01_000002] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 2.0 GB of 2 GB physical memory used; 2.9 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_e35_1491556562442_5086_01_000002 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 64750 64748 64750 64750 (bash) 0 0 108654592 306 /bin/bash -c /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java -Xms724m -Xmx724m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1448m -Djava.library.path=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/lib/native/ -Dlog.file=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1491556562442_5086/container_e35_1491556562442_5086_01_000002/taskmanager.log -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:logback.xml -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnTaskManagerRunner --configDir . 1> /var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1491556562442_5086/container_e35_1491556562442_5086_01_000002/taskmanager.out 2> /var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1491556562442_5086/container_e35_1491556562442_5086_01_000002/taskmanager.err 
    |- 64756 64750 64750 64750 (java) 269053 57593 2961149952 524252 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java -Xms724m -Xmx724m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1448m -Djava.library.path=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/lib/native/ -Dlog.file=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1491556562442_5086/container_e35_1491556562442_5086_01_000002/taskmanager.log -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:logback.xml -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnTaskManagerRunner --configDir . 

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

There are no application/code side error.

Need help to understand what could be the cause ?

Answer (score 2):

The job is killed, because it exceeds memory limits set in Yarn.
See this part of your error message:

```
Container [pid=64750,containerID=container_e35_1491556562442_5086_01_000002] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 2.0 GB of 2 GB physical memory used; 2.9 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

Comment: this could be memory consumption from application or due to some yarn resource management process ? I am running job on parallelism 1.

Comment: I tried to monitor with jmap on task manager and did not get anything that can cause out of memory . No out of memory error in logs also .

Comment: I tried to run container with 4 gb memory . This time job ran for 20 hours and then failed with same exception . Only this I noticed is there was increase of 15 mb in permgen space.